# CASE WHEN DATE then 'Login'

Tags: date, case

So I want to us.passwordDate to return as LOGIN in the lg.eventType column. How do I do that?

SELECT 
      us.userId 
      ,lg.createDate 
      ,lg.eventType,

CASE us.PasswordDate
    WHEN 'DATEVALUE' THEN 'Login'
    WHEN NULL THEN ' '
       else ''
    END

```
       FROM dbo.contact us ---- contacts

full outer join dbo.login lg ----logins
    on us.userid=lg.userid


    where lg.eventType in ('Login','Logout')
    OR  lg.eventType IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT us.userId ,lg.createDate ,lg.eventType,
(CASE us.PasswordDate WHEN 'DATEVALUE' THEN 'Login' WHEN NULL THEN ' ' else '' END) as LOGIN
FROM dbo.contact us ---- contacts
full outer join dbo.login lg ----logins
        on us.userid=lg.userid
where lg.eventType in ('Login','Logout')
        OR  lg.eventType IS NULL
```